# Read multiple integers in one line into a vector(C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have to be able to read a line of integers like this from cin: 1 2 3 5 10 9
all in one line. I don't know how many integers the user enters.
Then I need to store them. Since I don't know the number of inputs I use a vector. But I can't quite solve this issue.

This is what I have so far:

```c
cout << "Enter numbers: " << endl;
vector <int> v;
int input;
while(cin >> input){
    v.push_back(input);
}
```

The problem with the above code is that only the first integer gets read to the vector,
and that the cin does not terminate when I hit enter.

Any advice on how to read all the values into the vector and to terminate the cin after that?

Any help is appreciated

Frank

Comment: The code you have posted should work. Can you explain the issue in more detail?

Comment: You could read the numbers as a string using `std::getline`.  Next, pass the string to `std::istringstream` and extract from `std::istringstream`.